# removing elements while iterating the Collection

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I read that the correct way of  removing elements while iterating the Collection, is this way (using iterator):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(12);
list.add(18);

Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()) {
    itr.remove();
}
```

But, I receive `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException` and I don't know why.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Read the doc, it clearly states: `IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method`

Answer (score 6):

You never advanced to the next element by calling [the `next()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) on the iterator.  Try:

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Removing " + itr.next());  // Call next to advance
    itr.remove();
}
```